# css to make site horizontally scrollable

Tags: css

Can someone just confirm that I am on the right path here. Basically what I want to do is allow the user to browse horizontally (in responsive mode) on the page if needed. Would this be the correct CSS to do this:

```
padding-top: 0;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 5px solid #fff;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: but if I remove this then page won't be horizontally scrollable?

Comment: overflow-x:auto; this make horizontally scrollable if content not fit the width

Comment: so no need to add all the other lines, as long as overflow-x:auto; is there then the page will be horizontally scrollable in responsive mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make something horizontal scrollable it for examaple needs to not break `white-spaces` or to have a `min-width`, so setting `overflow: scroll;` is not needed unless you want the scrollbar to be there all the time.

Using `white-space`

```css
.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
</div>
```

Using `min-width`

```css
.wrapper {
    min-width: 1500px;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    bla bla bla bla 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested this now and looks like this can also work. Only thing when using `min-width`, the content is spread all over the page horizontally. Is there way to not spread it out?

Comment: The purpose of `min-width` is to set it to elements which you don't want to become less wider than a certain width. Then, when the browser width is smaller than the sum of these elements width, horizontal scrollbars will automatically get created by the browser.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for explaining.